# Laplace transform of an product of functions.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

The Laplace transform for the derivatives of an appropiate function holds the relation:
$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{d^k}{dt^k}f(t)\right)(s) 
= s^k\mathcal{L}(f(t))(s) 
- \sum_{m=0}^{k-1}s^{(k-1)-m}\frac{d^m}{dt^m}f(t)\,\Bigg|_{t=0}
$$

There is a formule for
$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{d^k}{dt^k}(t f(t))\right)(s)?
$$

When developing this expression, the calculations are going to get very complicated, so I ask if there is any known method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put $f(t)=tf(t)$. The formula will be:
$$
-s^k \partial_s F(s)+\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}s^{(k-1)-m} (mf^{(m-1)}(0))
$$
where, $F(s)$ is the laplace transform of $f(t)$